# Initialize member in class constructor and pass member down to base class at the same time

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor-injection, member-initialization

I have a main class (MyClass) derived from MyBase. Also I have a Helper class (used by MyClass) derived from HelperBase (used by MyBase). Is there a way to initialize the Helper in the constructor initialization of MyClass and also pass the helper down to MyBase that takes a HelperBase as constructor argument?
Something as follows:

EDIT: forgot to derive Helper from HelperBase (as mentioned in the comments) fixed that in the sample code

```cpp
//-------------------------------------------
// HelperBase.h
class MyBase;

// HelperBase holds a ref to MyBase
class HelperBase {
public:
    HelperBase(MyBase& i_ParentBase);

protected:
    MyBase& m_ParentBase;
};
// HelperBase.cpp
HelperBase::HelperBase(MyBase& i_ParentBase)
    : m_ParentBase(i_ParentBase)
{}
//-------------------------------------------
// Helper.h
class MyClass;

// Helper holds a ref to MyClass
class Helper : public HelperBase{
public:
    Helper(MyClass& i_Parent);

protected:
    MyClass& m_Parent;
};
//-------------------------------------------
// MyBase.h
// MyBase holds a ref to HelperBase
class MyBase {
public:
    MyBase(HelperBase& i_HelperBase);

protected:
    HelperBase& m_HelperBase;
};
// MyBase.cpp
MyBase::MyBase(HelperBase& i_HelperBase) : m_HelperBase(i_HelperBase)
{}
//-------------------------------------------
// MyClass.h
// MyClass holds and initializes an instance of Helper
class MyClass : public MyBase
{
public:
    MyClass();

protected:
    Helper m_Helper;
};
// MyClass.cpp
MyClass::MyClass()
    : MyBase(m_Helper), // <-- this is the problem !!!
    m_Helper(*this)
{}
//-------------------------------------------
// Helper.cpp
Helper::Helper(MyClass& i_Parent)
    : HelperBase(i_Parent),
      m_Parent(i_Parent)
{}
//-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Did you forget to derive `Helper` from `HelperBase`? Then, in `Helper` constructor, you'll need `: HelperBase(i_Parent)`, and the constructor itself needs to be moved down below the definition of `MyClass`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, obviously you're absolutely right. I fixed that now.

Comment: Please create an answer post.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned out the code works as above. There was a hidden/not so obvious naming convention clash that made the thing not compiling as expected (and the compile error did not reveal that at first sight). Sorry for that.